# How to restrict width div element into table element

Tags: html, css, width

I have css file

```
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px;
}
```

And i have html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mytablediv.css">
<table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td><div style="width:1000px;">div</div></td></tr></table>
```

I can't change html file but i can change css file.

How to restrict width div element into table element and make it 400px?

I tried div{ max-width:100% !important;} and it dont't work.
Width of table with div is 1000px but i need 400 px.

Comment: You have to override `width: 100% !important`

`table div {
    width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment `important` is really a valid fix. In msot cases such as this one it would be just a cover up and shifting away from the actual issue.

Comment: I know, but he cant configure the html. just the css

Comment: Simply set the `max-width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a valid solution, because you cant change the html!

```
table div {  width: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just limit the max-width with `max-width: 400px`

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width:1000px;">div</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```